# Windows remote desktop through NAT

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, nat

I just setup remote desktop to my Windows server 2012 R2. Thi works great from LAN. How can I setup remote desktop from outside of the LAN. I have tried NAT like this:

```
192.168.1.200 = windows server's IP

192.168.1.200:80 -->> my_public_IP:10200
```

when I want connect to it like this, it doesn't work. Maybe other local port..?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/12005/what-port-should-i-open-to-allow-remote-desktop  (Google is your friend.)

Comment: And this topic is also related: http://serverfault.com/questions/534100/accessing-remote-desktop-on-multiple-windows-machines-behind-nat/761983#761983

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Windows vista onwards provides secure RDP  connectivity over IPv6 without port forwarding configuration on NAT. This feature is called WICN & it gives a unique name to your computer using which you can directly RDP to the machine. Please check the below link to enable & use it:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb727045.aspx

Comment: This doesn't work outside of the network.

Comment: If the destination PC is behind a NAT, to get this to work, in Windows Firewall an explicit rule must be added for the executable to allow for traffic over NAT travesal (in the Advanced tab).